# Haskell: Filtering based on an index vector, using only basic higher-order functions

Tags: haskell, filter, higher-order-functions

**The problem**

I have a vector ***a*** of size *N* holding sample data, and another vector ***b*** of size *M* (*N>M*) holding indices. I would like to obtain a vector ***c*** of size *N* containing the filtered elements from ***a*** based on the indices in ***b***.

**The question**

Is it possible to implement the desired function without using list comprehension, just basic higher-order functions like map, zipWith, filter, etc. (more precisely, their equivalents mapV, zipWithV, filterV, etc.)

**Prerequisites:**

I am using a Haskell Embedded Domain Specific Language ([ForSyDe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ForSyDe-3.1.1), module [ForSyDe.Shallow.Vector](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ForSyDe-3.1.1/docs/ForSyDe-Shallow-Vector.html)), limited to a set of hardware synthesize-able functions. In order to respect the design methodology, I am allowed to use only the provided functions (thus I cannot use list comprehensions, etc.)

Comment: List comprehensions can be fairly trivially translated to `map`, `filter`, `zipWith`, etc. In fact, list comprehensions are just syntactic sugar for monadic functions, and your `Vector` type can be made a monad, so you could could just write the list comprehension version and turn on `MonadComprehensions`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Disclaimer:

I did not test this code for functionality because cabal started bugging around. It worked well for lists and as I transformed every vector to a list, it **should** work fine although problems may arise.

---

Try this:

```
indexFilter :: (Num b, Eq b, Enum b) => Vector a -> Vector b -> Vector a
indexFilter vector indices = vector (map fst (filter (\x -> (snd x) `elem` (fromVector indices)) vectorMap))
 where
   vectorMap = zip (fromVector vector) [0..]
```

`indexFilter` takes a list of tuple of the form `(<element>, <index>)` and then returns a vector of all elements which index is in the vector b. `vectorMap` is a just a zip of the elements of a and their indices in the vector.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying your method right now, translating it into my problem (applying some constraints to make it synthesizable). On the other hand, it seems like an excellent answer, and makes perfect sense.

Comment: @GeorgeUngureanu Let me know if any further problems arise

Comment: I have marked this answer as the correct one because it **DOES** answer my question. I did not solve my problem though, because of several design methodology constraints which are not mentioned. Also, the answer provided triggered the train of thought that lead to the solution(s) described below.

Answer (score 4):

Although the answer provided by [ThreeFx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3032349/threefx) is a correct answer to the question, it did not solve my problem due to several constraints enforced by the design methodology ([ForSyDe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ForSyDe-3.1.1)), which were not mentioned:

- lists cannot be used (they cannot be synthesized to other backends). ForSyDe provides two data containers: Signal (for temporal span) and Vector (for spatial span). This should ensure analyzability for system synthesis.
- `elem` does not have a ForSyDe.Shallow.Vector implementation

**Solution 1**

Using only what the library provides, the shortest solution I found is:

```
indexFilter1     :: (Num b, Eq b, Enum b) => Vector a 
                     -> Vector b 
                     -> Vector (Vector a)
indexFilter1 v = mapV (\idx -> selectV idx 1 1 v)
```

The output vector can further be unwrapped, depending on the further usage.

**Solution 2**

Translating [ThreeFx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3032349/threefx)'s solution to satisfy the constraints mentioned:

```
 indexFilter       :: (Num b, Eq b, Enum b) => Vector a 
                      -> Vector b 
                      -> Vector a
 indexFilter v idx = mapV (fst) (filterV (\x -> elemV (snd x) idx) vectorMap)
     where
       vectorMap = zipWithV (\a b -> (b, a)) (iterateV size (+1) 0) v
       size      = lengthV v
       elemV a   = foldlV (\acc x -> if x == a then True else acc) False
```